# i write on a file and read it but it seems when i run again

Tags: python

I want to write a file that says `hello guys how are you` but each word must be an item of list. Here is my code. It shows nothing when I run it, when I run second time it shows item by item as I want. But when I click text file, it is written two times.

```
with open('stavanger.txt','r+') as f: # file closes itself with with open as filename command
  words = ['hello\n','guys\n','how\n', 'are\n','you\n']
  f.writelines(words)
  for i in f:
    x=i.rstrip().split(',')#turn text file into list and we seperate list items by comma .
    print(x)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using the `'r+'` mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that writing to a file uses a ***buffer***. So after the line `f.writelines(words)` nothing really happened. Only the buffer changed.

In effect, the file still haven't changed and the file pointer is still at the beginning of the file. So the second time you run your code you see the content printed, which leaves the file pointer at the end of the file and only then the buffer is passed to the file and you have the duplicated content.

Simply use `mode='w'` if you just want to write to a file...

Answer (score 1):

You start reading the file from where the writing stopped. It is better to open the file first for writing, then for reading

Something like this

```
with open('stavanger.txt', 'w') as f:  # file closes itself with with open as filename command
    words = ['hello\n', 'guys\n', 'how\n', 'are\n', 'you\n']
    f.writelines(words)

with open('stavanger.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        x = i.rstrip().split(',')  # turn text file into list and we seperate list items by comma .
        print(x)
```